# What type of mammal does this fossil tooth belong to?

Tags: fossils, paleontology

The fossil tooth was found western South Dakota in the early 1980s.
I can't be sure on the location.  It might have been collected from Belle Reservoir, near Belle Fourche, Butte County, South Dakota, USA.
What type of mammal does this fossil tooth belong to?

[image: Top view of fossil tooth]
[image: Side view of Fossil tooth]

Comment: That's an awesome mystery,  it's somewhere in between a bear and a monkey (very odd) not a ruminant of any kind. http://www.thefossilforum.com/index.php?/forum/14-fossil-id/ it seems that prior to the WWW in 1980, the community had to shelve stuff without photos and emails. Someone's got to recall where it's from, it's stunning. if it's less than 30k yrs it may have DNA? It must be many millions of years.

Comment: Point of stating early 1980s is to say it was legally obtained.  The site is now  off-limits being on federal land.

Comment: some input from a biologist had been helpful on this one.

Comment: I'd have naively thought this would be better on like Biology SE, but perhaps I'm wrong!  Do suppose paleontology could be loosely on topic here with it's tie ins to geology... and not sure it'd hold well anywhere else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's an entelodont, South Dakota is famous for it's Oligocene mammalian faunas which include entelodonts such as Archaeotherium and Daeodon. 
[image]

here is an http://i.ebayimg.com/images/i/181202162847-0-1/s-l1000.jpg for comparison:
[image]

Thanks to the guys at [fossilforum](http://www.thefossilforum.com/index.php?/topic/82219-what-is-this-north-american-megafauna-fossil-tooth/), they knew in less than a day. this question could have stayed on here for a year so i was impatient.